# Failed to access database using JDBC driver

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

I'm trying to compile a program that needs to acess the SyBase,

I'm using the "jconn4.jar" as a driver, and my connection string is the following:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sybase:Tds://Server:Port", "User", "Password");
            System.out.println(conn);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
```

So I get this:

> java.sql.SQLException: JZ0D5: Error loading protocol com.sybase.jdbc4.server=xxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx;port=xxx;eng=xxx;database=contabil;links=tcpip(port=xxx).Server=//xxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx;port=xxx;eng=xxx;database=xxx;links=tcpip(port=xxx).
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at teste.DBproxyConnectionImple.getEmpresasAtivas(DBproxyConnectionImple.java:420)
> at teste.APIdatabase.main(APIdatabase.java:29)

I don't know if the error comes from the Driver or if its comming from the server.
I don't know even if i'm using the correct driver.

FULL CODE:

```
public class APIdatabase {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("API iniciada em: " + new java.util.Date());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "execução iniciada");
    DBproxyConnection DBUp = new DBproxyConnectionImple();
    firebaseDBConnect firebaseDB = new firebaseDBConnectImpl();
    Connection conn = DBUp.connect();
    ResultSet r = DBUp.getActiveEnterprises();

public ResultSet getActiveEnterprises() {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        //Cria um statement
        Statement stmt = this.conn.createStatement();

        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM (...));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }

    return rs;
}

public DBproxyConnectionImple() {
    this.server = "//xxxx";
    this.port = "xxx";
    this.db = "xxx";
    this.eng = "xxx";
    this.user = "xxx";
    this.password = "xxx";
    this.dbDriver = "jdbc:sybase:";
}

/**
 *
 * @param server
 * @param port
 * @param db
 * @param eng
 * @param user
 * @param password
 * @param dbDriver
 * @return
 */

@Override
public Connection connect(String server, String port, String db, String eng, String user, String password, String dbDriver) {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        //Cria uma conexão
        //conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbDriver
        //        + "Server=" + server
        //        + ";uid=" + user
        //        + ";pwd=" + password
        //        + ";port=" + port
        //        + ";eng=" + eng
        //        + ";database=" + db
        //        + ";links=xxx:xxx");
        
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sybase:Tds://xxx:xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
        System.out.println(conn);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }

    return conn;
```

Comment: I hope you are loading the driver, aren't you? Its recommended that you share the full code and full stack trace.

Comment: Yes, i'm importing java.sql.DriverManager; and it is ok. i'll edit the post with the full code

Comment: the stack trace still shows only a portion

Comment: @beastlyCoder it is ok now?

Comment: do you have sybase driver downloaded?

Comment: Yes, is the jconn4.jar the correct driver? I downloaded it from a "x" website and I dont know if it's corrupted, i dont have found yet the official download

Comment: The `NullPointerException` is caused by the fact that you catch and print the exception of the driver, and then continue as if nothing happens. As a result, your connection is `null`, which will then throw a `NullPointerException` when you dereference it. Revise your exception handling. Don't just print exceptions, either (wrap and) rethrow them or make sure that your application doesn't continue on as if everything is OK. As to the original exception, make sure you include the full exception stacktrace in your question (`e.printStackTrace()`), not just printing the exception `toString()`.